# spirit::qi::grammar-name with different char size

Tags: c++, boost, grammar, boost-spirit-qi

I am making a parser with spirit::qi and aim for making it compatible with different char sizes.

```
template < typename Iterator >
struct grammar : qi::grammar < Iterator >
{
    grammar () : grammar::base_type ( file, alter_string_size_to < Iterator::value_type > ( _szFile ) )
    {

    }

    qi::rule < Iterator > file;
};
```

Given that

```
alter_string_size_to < Iterator::value_type > ( _szFile )
```

successfully returns a pointer to a string containing _szFile in the required char size.

When I compile with

```
Iterator = std::wstring::const_iterator
```

I get following error message

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'unsigned short *' to 'const std::string &'
```

So .. grammar::base_type is only expecting an const std::string & as the second parameter.
My question is, how can I tell qi::grammar to expect a string with its Iterators value_type size ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I said so in my post .. if Iterator::value_type is char, it returns a const char * ... when its wchar_t, it returns const wchar_t * ... I didn't include any code because it has absolutely no purpose, the question is how grammar::base_type accepts something else than const std::string & as 2nd parameter, like for example const std::wstring & ...

Edit: comment deleted before i was done writing my answer ^.^ Anyway i leave this in, in case someone else asks what alter_string_size_to is ..

Comment: In your first code example you are lacking a `typename` in front of `Iterator::value_type` (assuming it is meant to be a type nested inside `Iterator`).

Comment: Yes, I got it the next moment.. But I have bad news for you )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined as follows in the source:

```
    grammar(
        start_type const& start
      , std::string const& name_ = "unnamed-grammar")
    : proto::extends<terminal, base_type>(terminal::make(reference_(start)))
    , name_(name_)
    {}

    std::string name_;
```

So you can't. As it's stated in the doc:

> name is an optional string that gives the grammar its name, useful for debugging and error handling.

So, you'll have to make your own lookup based on it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was hoping for a tricky work-around with some more complex qi::grammar or so which I haven't read about yet. I still can't really believe it, with all that template-jungle the makers of spirit haven't thought about making the grammar/rule names - used for error output - the same charsize as the input it parses .. If thats really it, then its a huge fail .. Ima wait some longer in hope there is someone seeing my question who knows a not to hard workaround before I toggle your answer as accepted.